# Binary Search Tree implementation giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

This is the c++ code to implement binary search tree where program gets seg. fault:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stack>

struct BSTNode
{
    int info;
    struct BSTNode *left, *right;
};

class BST
{
    private:
        //BSTNode *root;
    public:
        void rpreorder(BSTNode*);
        void rinorder(BSTNode*);
        void rpostorder(BSTNode*);
        BSTNode * search(BSTNode*, int);
        BSTNode* insert(BSTNode*, int);
};

void BST:: rpreorder(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return ;
    std::cout<<" "<<root->info;
    rpreorder(root->left);
    rpreorder(root->right);
}

void BST:: rinorder(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root = NULL)
        return ;
    rinorder(root->left);
    std::cout<<" "<<root->info;
    rinorder(root->right);
}

void BST:: rpostorder(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return ;
    rpostorder(root->left);
    rpostorder(root->right);
    std::cout<<" "<<root->info;
}

BSTNode * BST:: search(BSTNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return root;
    if(data < root->info)
        return search(root->left, data);
    else if(data > root->info)
        return search(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

BSTNode* BST:: insert(BSTNode *root, int data)
{
    BSTNode* parent;
    BSTNode* newNode = new BSTNode;
    newNode->info = data;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    if(root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        parent = root;
        while(parent != NULL)
        {
            if(data < parent->info)
            {
                if(parent->left == NULL)
                    parent->left = newNode;
                parent = parent->left;
            }
            else if(data > parent->info)
            {
                if(parent->right == NULL)
                    parent->right = newNode;
                parent = parent->right;
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    int choice, value;
    BST obj;
    BSTNode *root = NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n Enter the choice : \n 1. To insert \n 2. To search \n 3. recursive preorder \n 4. recursive inorder \n 5. recursive \
            postorder \n 6. EXIT \n : ";
        std::cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"\n Enter element to insert : ";
                std::cin>>value;
                root = obj.insert(root, value);
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout<<"\n Enter the element to search : ";
                std::cin>>value;
                {
                    BSTNode* temp;
                    temp = obj.search(root, value);
                    if(temp == NULL)
                        std::cout<<"\n Element not found "<<std::endl;
                    else
                        std::cout<<"\n The element found ";
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                obj.rpreorder(root);
                break;
            case 4:
                obj.rinorder(root);
                break;
            case 5:
                obj.rpostorder(root);
                break;
            case 6:
                exit(0);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The seg. fault is coming in this segment of above code :

```
void BST:: rinorder(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root = NULL)
        return ;
    rinorder(root->left); // <- this line gives seg. fault
    std::cout<<" "<<root->info;
    rinorder(root->right);
}
```

There is one more problem to this code :

After inserting only one element in BST I can't insert more elements into the BST.

Comment: Use `if (root == NULL)` instead of `if (root = NULL)` in `BST::rinorder()`.  I am not sure if this be the only problem.  I won't post this because it is a simple typo.

Comment: oh.. thanks... can you come to the second part of the problem?

Comment: @Singham, what do you mean when you say "I can't insert more elements into the BST"?  Why can't you insert?  What happens?  Does the program crash?

Comment: @Singham You have an infinite loop in your insertion. You find a null pointer on , say,  `parent->left`, so you assign the new node, but don't `break`. When you hit `parent = parent->left` you now have `parent` referring to your new node just inserted, and since its value must be *equal* to the input test value, neither of the tests (less or greater) are true. Thus parent doesn't move,and the cycle repeats ad-infinitum. Debugging: It's What's for Dinner (tm).

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thanks :)  your solution works awesome. But I didn't get your last statement `Debugging: It's What's for Dinner ->"(tm)"<-`

Comment: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol).